# Darchei Shalom in Halachah

Tags: gentiles, halacha-theory, halacha

Halachic Literature will, when relevant, promote certain permitted activities with respect to Gentiles because of "Darchei Shalom" (Ways of Peace).

Do we ever find situations where activities that are prohibited/problematic according to halachah are allowed because of Darchei Shalom?

Answer (score 5):

HaRav Yaakov Ariel - Ohala Shel Torah – Yoreh Deah 19 says that you may eat in a person's house where the dishes are not Toiveled due to Darchei Shalom.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12514/eating-on-someone-elses-untoveled-dishes discusses this as well. Does Harav Ariel clarify whether it <i>is prohibited</i>, but we are lenient and permit it due to darchei shalom OR are we lenient because it is a machlokes AND darchei shalom causes us to follow the lenient opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Yevamos 65: says that you may lie for Darchei Shalom.

יבמות סה: - "אמר ר' אילעא משום רבי אלעזר בר' שמעון, מותר לו לאדם לשנות בדבר השלום

Comment: While this is certainly related, I'm not certain that we can infer that this is not an independent din within the halachos of speaking truthfully rather than an application of the external principal of "darchei shalom"?